# Правильное употребление слов в предложении

Tags: употребление-слов

Поймали много рыбы: лещей, карасей, леньков.. Собирали маслята, грузди, сыроежки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если про падеж перечисляемых существительных, то все правильно.
Рыба одушевленная, грибы - нет.
Сложность возникает только с маслятами. Существительное неодушевленное, но по форме напоминает одушевленное. 
Связано с переосмыслением строения слова "опенок", которое на самом деле однокоренное с "пень", но "-енок" воспринимается как суффикс, подобный тому, что в "жеребенок" или "теленок". Отсюда и форма "опята", вытеснившая ранее нормативную "опенки". 
Тем не менее одушевленности слово "опята" не приобрело. Поэтому "собрали опята", Не "опят". Или уж "собрали опенки", по старому варианту.

Есть еще форма "маслята", с ней еще сложнее, она дальше продвинулась в сторону одушевленности, "собрать маслят" уже не выглядит неправильным.